# Median Calculation in Excel with Conditions

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013, median

I am having trouble getting the following Excel formula to work. I think I am having an issue with my parenthesis. I am trying to take the median based off of 3 conditions. The last condition is a date range.

```
=MEDIAN(IF($G$3:$G$458=$K$3,IF($A$3:$A$458=M$3,IF(AND($E$3:$E$458>DATEVALUE("1/1/2014"),$E$3:$E$458<DATEVALUE("12/31/2014")),$H$3:$H$458))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is correct you just need to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array formula.

Whenever you apply a formula (`E3:E458=$E$458`) to a range within one cell you need to make the calculation an array formula.